# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after setting up HTTP Listener in Glassfish

Tags: jsf, glassfish, httplistener

I'm hosting a JSF application on my server and, as such things are, it's external access address is P:8080/app_name, which is not very user friendly. Thus, I decided to create a external friendly address to it:

1º) I registered such address in a DNS rerouting it www.good_app_address.com to IP:80

2º) I created a HTTP Listener in Glassfish for port 80 and a virtual server for such listener for, whenever a request from www.good_app_address.com arrived at port 80, it would be rerouted to /app_name

This worked fine, however, after redirecting user to the correct address the URL still would show IP/app_name, instead of the www.good_app_address.com as I expected. I know that, in order to get rid of /app_name I just have to change the context root for this app, but I'm having a hard time changing IP to www.good_app_name.com

I found in my HTTP Listener the option Server Name, which states that it's an "Alias name for the server". I inputed there www.good_app_address.com and now it changes IP to www.good_app_address.com, but causes the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

How do I properly set www.good_app_address.com as my application URL?

Comment: So it works when you use a plain html page in a similar webapp?

Comment: I can access my app pages normally, but the URL will still show IP/app_name/page.xhtml . The other apps I have hosted in this server work the same way, but I still have not tried to add a good URL to them.